# Javascript: Cannot show alert before page unload

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Following is the code I've written for asking confirmation to user on page unload:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var pageLeaveEvent = window.attachEvent || window.addEventListener;
        var checkedEvent = window.attachEvent ? 'onbeforeunload' : 'beforeunload'; //Make IE7, IE8 compatible.

        pageLeaveEvent(checkedEvent, function (e) { //For >= IE7, Chrome & Firefox.
            debugger;
            return 'Are you sure you want to leave page?';
        });
    });
```

When page is refreshed, the debugger inside `pageLeaveEvent` is hit however the alert is not shown. I am banging my head against wall to fix this and not getting any clue why this is happening. Please help me find out the reason.

As a side note, previously I had used same code in ASP.NET MVC project and it worked, now I am  trying to get same code working in ASP.NET Web Forms project. I found this code [here](http://devzone.co.in/show-confirmation-box-page-refresh-page-unload-using-javascript/).

Comment: If you remove `debugger`?...

Comment: You need to set retrunValue property of event: `var msg = 'Are you sure you want to leave page?';
        (e || window.event).returnValue = msg;
        return msg;`  [DOC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload)    **&&** [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/h6L6u7yu/)

Answer (score 0):

you missed the event returnValue configuration as in the tutorial you linked:

```
(e || window.event).returnValue = 'your_message';
```

Add it to your callback and it will work fine.